# How to implement Locking Group Headers grid in extjs 3.4?

Tags: extjs3, extjs4.2

[image]

In extjs 4.2 , this feature has  been implemented(as shown in the above image.). but how to implement them in extjs 3.4?

Comment: Grouping is done in extjs 3.4 using ColumnHeaderGroup.js and also Locking is achieved for normal grids using LockingGridView.js but however there is no example to view combination of these two views.

Comment: Maybe try this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?92797-3.1.1-Ext.ux.grid.LockingGroupingGridView